# Wiring Up Events from Custom Class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, event-handling

I've got a Placeholder on an ASP.NET form, a custom class that builds a table from multiple sources, and inside that custom class buttons are dynamically added to the table.

Everything is fine, except in my code behind (Databinding to a FormView) I can't figure out how to wire up my events.

In my custom Class, I have the following:

```
Dim Objective_addBtn As Button = New Button
Objective_addBtn.ID = 'I dynamically set the ID here
AddHandler Objective_addBtn.Click, AddressOf AddRow
```

In my custom class, I have the following:

```
Public Event AddNewRow As EventHandler

Private Sub AddRow(sender As Button, e As EventArgs)

    Select Case True
        Case sender.ID.Contains("ProblemBtn")

        Case sender.ID.Contains("GoalBtn")

        Case sender.ID.Contains("ObjectiveBtn")

            RaiseEvent AddNewRow(Me, EventArgs.Empty)

        Case sender.ID.Contains("TaskBtn")

        Case Else
            'Do Nothing - Should Not be here!
    End Select
End Sub
```

I've verified that I'm getting to the code block of RaiseEvent, but I can't figure out how to capture that event in my code behind.

My current code-behind:

```
Partial Class <mypage>
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private WithEvents CustomClass As New CustomClass

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handled Me.Load
        CustomClass = New CustomClass(Request.QueryString("pid"), Request.QueryString("sid"))

        AddHandler CustomClass.AddNewRow, AddressOf NewRow
    End Sub
End Class
```

Finally, also in the code behind, I have:

```
Protected Sub NewRow(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CustomClass.AddNewRow
    MsgBox("NewRow Test")
End Sub
```

NewRow is never fired, the MsgBox test never shows, and debugging step by step verifies that NewRow sub is never entered.

Comment: Your last functions indicates: "Handles TXPlan.AddNewRow". Isn't it "Handles CustomClass.AddNewRow"?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is.  I've got a boatload of code, trying to pare it down to the basics, lol.

Comment: Please vote up my comment for this :)

Comment: Nobody has anything more?

Answer (score 1):

Ha!  Got it working :)  Here's what I did:

First, in my Partial Class, I referenced -

```
Private WithEvents CustomClass as new CustomClass
```

I then in Page_Init set up -

```
CustomClass = New CustomClass(Request.QueryString("pid"), Request.QueryString("sid"))

AddHandler CustomClass.AddNewRow, AddressOf NewRow
```

Evidently you *must* set this up in Page_Init instead of Page_Load.  Now NewRow() is being executed.  Hope this helps someone out there!